# Normal Image resolution for Android

Tags: android

I want to know the normal image resolution for android applications and the optimal size of the animation frames[images].In my application,we are using several different frames for the animation part and the size of the .apk file is 6mb.our image size is ranging from 50kb to 700kb. can anyone tell me the exact resolution and size??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link:

http://anidea.com/technology/designer%E2%80%99s-guide-to-supporting-multiple-android-device-screens/